# How to append more than 1 nested node for XML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest, append

Good day everyone,

I am currently trying to append a metadata file. Sorry in advance if I did anything wrong, I am unfamiliar with editing XML codes in JS.. Thanks!
Currently, I am having difficulty getting the results that I expected. I am trying to insert 2 new nodes one nested over the other into the **newParentTestNode**.

I want to add a **couple of nodes within the TestNode** as seen in the results I want.. I can't seem to find a solution online. Please do help thanks!

I am currently getting this result:

```
<gmd:MTTEST><TESTNODE2/></gmd:MTTEST>
```

But the result I want is:

```
<gmd:MTTEST>
 <gmd:TestNode>
  <gmd:TestNode2>

  </gmd:TestNode2>
 </gmd:TestNode>
</gmd:MTTEST>
```

```
xmlTest: function (evt) { 
  if(this.item.metadata_standard_name == "Correct Data"){

        xmlString = this.item.sys_xml_clob;
       
        var metadataXmlString = jQuery.parseXML(xmlString); 

        let newParentTestNode = metadataXmlString.getElementsByTagName("gmd:MTTEST") 

        newNode = metadataXmlString.createElement("TestNode")
        newNode2 = metadataXmlString.createElement("TestNode2")

        let addMe = newNode.appendChild(newNode2)

        newParentTestNode[0].appendChild(addMe)        

        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(metadataXmlString);

        console.log(xmlString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`appendChild()` [returns the node that is appended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#return_value) not the parent node.

This means that `newNode.appendChild(newNode2)` returns `newNode2`, which you'll then append to your root node, effectively removing *TestNode2* from *TestNode* and appending it directly to *MTTEST*.

You don't need to assign the result of `appendChild` to a new `addMe` variable because appendChild modifies the structure in-place, so you gain nothing from the return value (as you already have variables referencing both the parent and the child element). So in the end you just need to append `newNode` (which will already contain `newNode2`) to `newParentTestNode`.